# Hive Data to Pandas Data frame

Tags: python, pandas, hadoop, hive

Newbie to Python.

How can i save the data from hive to Pandas data frame.

```
with pyhs2.connect(host, port=20000,authMechanism="PLAIN",user,password,
               database) as conn:
    with conn.cursor() as cur:
        #Show databases
        print cur.getDatabases()

        #Execute query
        cur.execute(query)

        #Return column info from query
        print cur.getSchema()

        #Fetch table results
        for i in cur.fetch():
            print i
        **columnNames = [a['columnName'] for a in  cur.getSchema()]
        print columnNames
        df1=pd.DataFrame(cur.fetch(),columnNames)**
```

Tried using column names. Didn't Work.

Pls. suggest something.

Comment: `Didn't Work.` can hardly be considered a good error description :)

Comment: I think blaze is the right tool for that - I haven't worked with it yet, though. This may be an interesting read for you: http://blaze.pydata.org/blog/2015/09/16/reddit-impala/

Comment: Thanks.. Cel for pointing that out. anyway issue resolved now. :)

Answer (score 13):

[pd.read_sql()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_sql.html) (pandas 0.24.0) takes a DB connection. Use [PyHive](https://github.com/dropbox/PyHive) connection directly with `pandas.read_sql()` as follows:

```py
from pyhive import hive
import pandas as pd

# open connection
conn = hive.Connection(host=host,port= 20000, ...)

# query the table to a new dataframe
dataframe = pd.read_sql("SELECT id, name FROM test.example_table", conn)
```

Dataframe's columns will be named after the hive table's. One can change them during/after dataframe creation if needed:

- via HiveQL: `SELECT id AS new_column_name ...`
- via columns attribute in `pd.read_sql()`

Comment: But it shows "pandas only supports SQLAlchemy connectable (engine/connection) or database string URI or sqlite3 DBAPI2 connection. Other DBAPI2 objects are not tested. Please consider using SQLAlchemy.
"

Answer (score 1):

You can try this: ( I'm pretty sure it will work)

```
res = cur.getSchema()
description = list(col['columnName'] for col in res)  ## for getting the column names of the table 

headers = [x.split(".")[1] for x in description] # for splitting the list if the column name contains a period

df= pd.DataFrame(cur.fetchall(), columns = headers)

df.head(n = 20)
```

Answer (score 0):

As I had fetched data before and was trying to fetch again, so was getting empty Data Frame.

```
cur.execute(query)
val=cur.fetchall()
columnNames = [a['columnName'] for a in  cur.getSchema()]
df=pd.DataFrame(data=val,columns=columnNames)
#print df
return df
```